# How to rename backup files, using its backup version as a suffix to file name and making it no longer hidden

Tags: command-line, bash

I have been working with a large number of image files. Part of this was moving all image file types that were spread across 1000+ directories into a single directly. There were many pictures that had the same exact name, but were indeed different pictures. I used the following one-liner to do so:

```
find . -type f -exec mv --backup=t '{}' /media/DATA-HDD/AllImages \;
```

I did it this way so that any images that had the same name would get a hidden backup file made, instead of overwriting. It worked very well, but now I have another problem that I need to solve.

Now, I, of course, have a lot of tiles that are something like the following:

```
DSC_0616.NEF
DSC_0616.NEF.~1~
DSC_0616.NEF.~2~
```

What I am looking to do is run a command (or script), that will rename any of these hidden files by adding the backup number as a suffix to the file name, and remove the .~[bu#]~ to make them unique file names and no hidden. So, like so:

```
DSC_0616.NEF
DSC_0616_1.NEF
DSC_0616_2.NEF
```

I have spent the better part of a couple of hours trying to research to attempt this myself, but can't really find anything that can help me get there that is within my realm of knowledge on the topic.

Answer (score 2):

So long as you're certain everything is named consistently as you described above, some regular expressions can get the job done through a shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# sets the file separator to be only newlines, in case files have spaces in them
IFS=$'\n'
for file in $(find . -type f); do
        # parses just the number(s) between two tildes, and only at the end of the file
        number=$(echo $file | grep -Eo "~[0-9]+~$" | sed s/'~'/''/g)
        # if no match found, assume this is a "base" file that does not need to be renamed
        if [ "$number" == "" ]; then
                continue
        fi
        # parses the file name through "NEF", then deletes ".NEF"
        filename=$(echo $file |  grep -Eio "^.+\.NEF" | sed s/'\.NEF'/''/g )
        if [ "$filename" == "" ]; then
                continue
        fi
        mv -v $file $(echo "$filename"_"$number.NEF")
        # if anything went wrong, exit immediately
        if [ "$?" != "0" ]; then
                echo "Unable to move file $file"
                exit 1
        fi
done
```

This will work for descending through directories as well, just place the script and execute it with your working directory at the top of your project's directory tree. Running with example files like you provided:

```
###@###:~/project$ find . -type f
./DSC_0616.NEF.~8~
./DSC_0616.NEF.~5~
./DSC_0616.NEF.~1~
./DSC_0616.NEF.~7~
./DSC_0616.NEF.~3~
./DSC_0616.NEF.~4~
./DSC_0616.NEF.~9~
./DSC_0616.NEF.~2~
./DSC_0616.NEF.~6~
./lower_dir/DSC_0616.NEF.~8~
./lower_dir/DSC_0616.NEF.~5~
./lower_dir/DSC_0616.NEF.~1~
./lower_dir/DSC_0616.NEF.~7~
./lower_dir/DSC_0616.NEF.~3~
./lower_dir/DSC_0616.NEF.~4~
./lower_dir/DSC_0616.NEF.~9~
./lower_dir/DSC_0616.NEF.~2~
./lower_dir/DSC_0616.NEF.~6~
```

after running the script:

```
###@###:~/project$ find . -type f
./DSC_0616_1.NEF
./DSC_0616_3.NEF
./DSC_0616_7.NEF
./DSC_0616_5.NEF
./DSC_0616_2.NEF
./DSC_0616_9.NEF
./DSC_0616_6.NEF
./DSC_0616_8.NEF
./DSC_0616_4.NEF
./lower_dir/DSC_0616_1.NEF
./lower_dir/DSC_0616_3.NEF
./lower_dir/DSC_0616_7.NEF
./lower_dir/DSC_0616_5.NEF
./lower_dir/DSC_0616_2.NEF
./lower_dir/DSC_0616_9.NEF
./lower_dir/DSC_0616_6.NEF
./lower_dir/DSC_0616_8.NEF
./lower_dir/DSC_0616_4.NEF
```

Comment: I knew abstractly that this was basically what needed to be done, and I do understand, roughly, what you are doing here, but would never have been able to come up with this on my own! I appreciate it. I used .NEF as an example but I do have other file types as well. I will take this as a jumping off point. I think I can figure out how to apply this to all the file types that could be there with your examples and some research. Worse case, I can just change this and run one per each file type. In any event, I have all of this data backed up with playing around so if I screw it, it's NBD.

Comment: that's the best way to learn! Most of my scripts early on started without my full comprehension of what needed to be done, and real-world examples with reliable backups are the best tools.

Answer (score 1):

In the comments, the OP requested a solution that works for any extensions (not just .NEF), and I just had the same problem. : p

Here's one with somewhat more modern Bashisms than the first answer's:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Renames the $1 directory's backup files (produced by `cp` or `mv` with the
# option `--backup=numbered`) such that "foo.png.~17~" becomes "foo_17.png"
function rename_backups()
{
    for THING in "${1}"/*
    do
        if [[ -f "${THING}" &&
              "${THING}" =~ ^.+\/+.+\..+~([0-9]+)~$ ]] # Take "foo.png.~17~".
        then
            # Get the "17".
            local BACKUP_NUMBER=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}

            # Remove the "~17~", leaving "foo.png".
            local SANS_BACKUP_NUMBER="${THING%.*}"

            # Get the filename, "foo", and the extension, "png".
            local FILENAME="${SANS_BACKUP_NUMBER%.*}"
            local EXT="${SANS_BACKUP_NUMBER##*.}"

            # Rename to "foo_17.png".
            local NEW_NAME="${FILENAME}_${BACKUP_NUMBER}.${EXT}"

            while [[ -f "${NEW_NAME}" ]]
            do
                # If "foo_17.png" already exists for some reason, keep
                # increasing the number until we find an unused one.
                ((++BACKUP_NUMBER))
                NEW_NAME="${FILENAME}_${BACKUP_NUMBER}.${EXT}"
            done

            mv --no-clobber "${THING}" "${NEW_NAME}"
        fi
    done
}

rename_backups your/backup/directory/here/
```

The version below also supports *extensionless* files:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Renames the $1 directory's backup files (produced by `cp` or `mv` with the
# option `--backup=numbered`) such that:
#     - "foo.png.~17~" becomes "foo_17.png"
#     - "bar.~17~" becomes "bar_17"
function rename_backups()
{
    for THING in "${1}"/*
    do
        # We'll either have a file like "foo.png.~17~" or "bar.~17~".
        if [[ -f "${THING}" && "${THING}" =~ ^.+~([0-9]+)~$ ]]
        then
            # Get the "17".
            local BACKUP_NUMBER=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}

            # Remove the "~17~", leaving, e.g., "foo.png".
            local SANS_BACKUP_NUMBER="${THING%.*}"

            # Get the filename, "foo", and the extension, "png".
            local FILENAME="${SANS_BACKUP_NUMBER%.*}"
            local EXT="${SANS_BACKUP_NUMBER##*.}"

            if [[ "${FILENAME}" == "${SANS_BACKUP_NUMBER}" ]]
            then
                # This is a "bar.~17~" case, so rename to "bar_17".
                local NEW_NAME="${FILENAME}_${BACKUP_NUMBER}"

                while [[ -f "${NEW_NAME}" ]]
                do
                    # If "bar_17" already exists for some reason, keep
                    # increasing the number until we find an unused one.
                    ((++BACKUP_NUMBER))
                    NEW_NAME="${FILENAME}_${BACKUP_NUMBER}"
                done
            else
                # This is a "foo.png.~17~" case, so rename to "foo_17.png".
                local NEW_NAME="${FILENAME}_${BACKUP_NUMBER}.${EXT}"

                while [[ -f "${NEW_NAME}" ]]
                do
                    ((++BACKUP_NUMBER))
                    NEW_NAME="${FILENAME}_${BACKUP_NUMBER}.${EXT}"
                done
            fi

            mv --no-clobber "${THING}" "${NEW_NAME}"
        fi
    done
}

rename_backups your/backup/directory/here/
```